# Java English date format parsing

Tags: java

My problem is the following. I am reading a file and it contains a bunch of CSV lines. Each line contains some date in the format of `22-mar-2010` or similar i.e. with the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`. I want to convert this to ISO format so it becomes `2010-03-22`.

The code I have looks like this:

```
  private String convertDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter oldFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("en"));
    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, oldFormat);

    DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
    String newDate = parsedDate.format(newFormat);
    return newDate;
  }
```

The input looks something like this:

```
sdfdsfslk 28-mar-2007 dfdsljs
sdfdsfslk 20-apr-2014 dfdsljs
sdfdsfslk 13-oct-2005 dfdsljs
sdfdsfslk 20-may-2014 dfdsljs
sdfdsfslk 20-jan-2014 dfdsljs
sdfdsfslk 20-feb-2014 dfdsljs
```

If include the locale as above or use `withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` then it fails at the first row date string. The exception is:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '28-mar-2007' could not be parsed at index 3
```

If I remove the locale part and just have:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Then it works until it encounters a date such as `13-oct-2005`. It does not like the English 'oct' and fails at the `LocalDate.parse` row. If I convert oct to okt (Swedish, where I am) then it parses it.

Do I need to change my Locale completely or what is going wrong here? How can I get it to parse dates with months in English even though I am in Sweden?

Comment: A `Locale` is always involved. If you do not specify a `Locale` explicitly then your JVM’s current default locale is implicitly applied. So `okt` was successfully parsed because your JVM’s current default Swedish locale was applied on your behalf.

Comment: Yeah but problem was I was providing a Locale but that didn't approve lowercase month. Hence the conversion to uppercase to Mar.

Comment: No, really the problem is the incoming date used (a) improper English for the name of the month, & (b) a poor choice of format for a date value. As a workaround, see [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39213129/642706) for making a case-insensitive parser to accommodate the improper English. And educate the programmer of the source data about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). My comment above was to explain  why your removal of the `Locale` then succeeded with Swedish text. The implicit Swedish `Locale` expects lowercase month name while English expects initial-cap.

Comment: @BasilBourque, yeah the incoming date was one big issue and I didn't think that the English Locale differed with the Swedish in terms of case sensitivity. Thanks for your answer below. I have voted it up as it was a very nice way of doing it without the workaround. Unfortunately the backend is like 20 years old and no body goes near that system. We are trying to integrate away from it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that the first letter of the month is **lowercase**.
When you run the same code for `28-Mar-2007` instead of `28-mar-2007` everything works fine.

**One quick and dirty solution is:**

```
private String convertDate(String mydate) {

        String date = mydate;
        String firstLetter = date.substring(0,4).toUpperCase();
        String restLetters = date.substring(4).toLowerCase();
        date = firstLetter+restLetters;

        DateTimeFormatter oldFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("en"));
    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, oldFormat);

    DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
    String newDate = parsedDate.format(newFormat);
   return newDate;
  }
```

Comment: Correct Answer. This is an example of why we should always persist date-time values to text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Plirkee, that did indeed work and as you said, probably uppercase/lowercase issue that caused. Unfortunately it is a legacy backend so hard to changed the internal formatting there.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse ( 
    "13-oct-2005" , 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" )
        .toFormatter( Locale.US ) 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Plirkee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211385/642706) is correct: The English locales expect abbreviated month name to have an initial capital letter (uppercase).

## `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

Given this faulty input data, an easier workaround is to build a formatter that is case-insensitive. The `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class enables you to build more finely customized formatters that you can with a mere formatting code string pattern.

The java.time classes including `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` are thread-safe. So you can keep an instance around for repeated use.

## *Builder* pattern

Read up on the [*Builder* design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) if not familiar. Rather than call a constructor with a multitude of arguments, construct a Builder object with a call chain of various methods to suit your needs. At the end, ask that Builder to instantiate the object you really want, a `DateTimeFormatter` in this case.

## `.parseCaseInsensitive()`

The trick we need is the call to `.parseCaseInsensitive()`. You can verify that this call is the crucial ingredient by swapping with the commented-out line that omits this call.

```
//  DateTimeFormatterBuilder fbuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder ().appendPattern ( "dd-MMM-uuuu" );  // Case-sensitive by default.
DateTimeFormatterBuilder fbuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder ().parseCaseInsensitive ().appendPattern ( "dd-MMM-uuuu" );  // Case-insensitive to handle improper English.

String input = "13-oct-2005"; // Incorrect English. Should be uppercase 'Oct'.
DateTimeFormatter f = fbuilder.toFormatter ( Locale.US );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
```

> ld.toString() → 2005-10-13

## ISO 8601

Tip: When exchanging date-time values as text, always use standard [**ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than devise your own funky formats such as that seen in the Question. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: thanks for the tip on using the DateTimeFormatterBuilder. That looks mighty handy. I did see in the java doc that the examples are Jun but I didn't think it was case sensitive. But yeah for sure parsing it with .parseCaseInsensitive() looks much tidier.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String convertDate(String daterec) {
        String date = daterec;
        String firstLetter = date.substring(0,4).toUpperCase();
        String restLetters = date.substring(4).toLowerCase();
        date = firstLetter+restLetters;
        DateTimeFormatter dTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("en"));
        LocalDate lds = LocalDate.parse((date), dTF);
    return lds.toString();
  }
```

output same as accepted answer:

```
2007-03-28
2014-04-20
2005-10-13
2007-03-28
2014-01-20
2014-02-20
```

As already said, we need to keep the format, although there's negligible 2 lines of code which can be avoided since we are passing 'dd-MMM-yyyy' which also mean ISO standard ,I am little late so just posting for little less code